# Cannot destructure propery error - googleapi

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Error while using googleapi

my error:

> (node:7776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `data` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
>       at gmail.users.labels.list

the confusing for me is that everything works, it prints it out as it should but why does it give me an error about being null if it is clearly not?
how can this be solved?

This is my code:

```
var async = require('async-kit');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';

function test(methodname) {
  console.log('called');
  fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), methodname);
  });
}

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  console.log('authorized');
  const {
    client_secret,
    client_id,
    redirect_uris
  } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth, callback) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({
    version: 'v1',
    auth
  });
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    userId: 'me',
  }, (err, {
    data
  }) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      callback();
    }
    const labels = data.labels;
    console.log('got labels');
    if (labels.length) {
      interimlabels = labels;
      interimlabels.forEach((label) => {
        console.log(`- ${label.name}`);
      });
      callback();
    }
    else {
      console.log('No labels found.');
      callback();
    }
  });
}
var interimlabels = [];
async.series([
    function getStuff(callback) {
      test(listLabels);
      if (interimlabels.length != 0) {
        console.log('labels', interimlabels);
        callback();
      }
    }
  ])
  .exec(function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('shit');
    }
    else {
      console.log('done');
    }
  });
```

Edit: I just want to add that it wokr sperfectly, logs out as it should but after it gives me the error at the end
edit2: ok so if I remove the callback(); from the listLabels(); then the promiserejection goes away but then the code obviously will hang there, so what can be the problem with the callback?

Answer (score 0):

// You are getting an error and you have some fault in error handling. You were destruction the result from the google API. But in fact you were not getting any result, so it was showing the given error: `Cannot destructure propery error - googleapi`

// Try this code.

```
/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth, callback) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({
    version: 'v1',
    auth
  });
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    userId: 'me',
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err || !result) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      callback();
    } else {
      const labels = result.data.labels;
      console.log('got labels');
      if (labels.length) {
        interimlabels = labels;
        interimlabels.forEach((label) => {
          console.log(`- ${label.name}`);
        });
        callback();
      }
      else {
        console.log('No labels found.');
        callback();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this solves your query.

**Updated code:**

```
function listLabels(auth, callback) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({
    version: 'v1',
    auth
  });

  var request = gmail.users.labels.list({
    'userId': 'me'
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log("resp", resp);
    var labels = resp.labels;
    callback(labels);
  });
}
```

Comment: with this i get this: The API returned an error: TypeError: callback is not a function
(node:14052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback is not a function
    at gmail.users.labels.list

Comment: Try the updated code and tell if it works and if it doesn't then tell me what it logs?

Comment: request.execute(function(resp) {
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove ``gapi.client.``. try again now.

Comment: yes i did that myself, and after that i got that error

Comment: Can you try for different userID

Comment: no matter the user id it gives erroe at request.execute